# Try to learn python, NameError: global name 'controller' is not defined

Tags: python

updated

> Exception in Tkinter callback
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1536, in **call**
>       return self.func(*args)
>     File "tk_cp_successful.py", line 143, in 
>       command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))

My error is

> NameError: global name 'controller' is not defined

```
class LoginPage(tk.Frame):
     def __init__(self, parent, controller):
      global entry_1
      global entry_2
      tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
      label = tk.Label(self, text="test page")
      label.pack(pady=20,padx=20)

      label_1 = Label(self, text="Username")
      label_1.pack()
      label_2 = Label(self, text="Password")
      label_2.pack()
      entry_1 = Entry(self)
      entry_1.pack()
      entry_2 = Entry(self, show="*")
      entry_2.pack()
      label_1.grid(row=0, sticky=E)
      label_1.pack()
      label_2.grid(row=1, sticky=E)
      label_2.pack()
      entry_1.grid(row=0, column=1)
      entry_1.pack()
      entry_2.grid(row=1, column=1)
      entry_2.pack()
      checkbox = Checkbutton(self, text="Keep me logged in")

      checkbox.grid(columnspan=2)
      checkbox.pack()
      logbtn = Button(self, text="Login", command = self.tested)
      logbtn.grid(columnspan=2)
      logbtn.pack()


     def tested(self):
        #print("Clicked")
        username = entry_1.get()
        password = entry_2.get()

        #print(username, password)

        if username == "test" and password == "test":
            #box.showinfo("Login successful", "Welcome test")
            button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back to new page", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(newPage))
            button1.pack()
        else:
            box.showerror("Login failed", "Incorrect username")
```

Comment: `controller` is not "in scope". You passed it in as a parameter to the class, but you need to assign it to a field to use it in another method

Comment: this is the class------------                                                                                       class LoginPage(tk.Frame):
     def __init__(self, parent, controller):
      global entry_1
      global entry_2
      tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
      label = tk.Label(self, text="Page one")
      label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

      label_1 = Label(self, text="Username")
      label_1.pack()
      label_2 = Label(self, text="Password")
      label_2.pack()
      entry_1 = Entry(self)
      entry_1.pack()

Comment: Please don't use the comments for code. As you can tell, it looks awful

Comment: thank you. let me try other way.

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: thank you. my questions is how I can use controller in  "def tested(self)"?  or any other way I can use tested(self)?  after login page successful, I want to redirect to new test page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the controller into a member variable / field.

```
class LoginPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        self.controller = controller 
        # other code 

   def tested(self):
       # other code 
       # access with self.controller
```

Comment: thank you so much for the helps. after I change to member variable, and use with self.controller. it worked.   it really great to know

Comment: Sorry? Change what to what?

Comment: I can have a new page popup.

Comment: Is that a question? Or you are saying it works? If it did work the way you wanted, you can use the checkmark next to the answer to let others on the site know this was the solution to your problem.